# I want to resume my python from the state it was stopped , how do i do that?

Tags: python, praw

I'm inserting my code below. I couldn't really do anything on this topic, I'm still learning so that isn't helping either.

I'm inserting my code below. I couldn't really do anything on this topic, I'm still learning so that isn't helping either.

Someone suggested using pickle, JSON, or SQL but I'm not familiar with any of them.

I'm using replit so it automatically restarts the bot .

```
import praw 
import time
import random 
import requests
import sys
from sys import exit

print("Starting Magic............")

print(reddit.user.me())

REDDIT_USERNAME=(reddit.user.me())

response = requests.get("https://www.reddit.com/user/{}/about.json".format(REDDIT_USERNAME),  headers = {'User-agent': 'hiiii its {}'.format(REDDIT_USERNAME)}).json()
if "error" in response:
 if response["error"] == 404:
      print("account {} is shadowbanned. poor bot :( shutting down the script...".format(REDDIT_USERNAME))
      sys.exit()
 else:
      print(response)
else:
    print("{} is not shadowbanned! We think..".format(REDDIT_USERNAME))


title = input("Enter an epic title: ") 
title2 = input("Enter an epic title: ") 


url = input("Enter a sassy link: ") 
url2 = input("Enter a sassy link: ") 



print("Reading reddit list")
subredit_list = open("data.txt", "r")
subreddits = subredit_list.read().split(',')


for subreddit in subreddits:
  try:
    print(subreddit)
    reddit.validate_on_submit = True
    submission = reddit.subreddit(subreddit).submit(title,url=url)
    time.sleep(10)
    print ("done")
  except Exception as err:
    print("Exception for subreddit {}, {}".format(subreddit, err))
  t= random.randint(615,815)
  seconds = "Sleeping for {} seconds before proceeding".format(t)
  print(seconds)
  time.sleep(t)

print("Reading reddit list")
subredit_list = open("data.txt", "r")
subreddits = subredit_list.read().split(',')


for subreddit in subreddits:
  try:
    print(subreddit)
    reddit.validate_on_submit = True
    submission = reddit.subreddit(subreddit).submit(title2,url=url2)
    time.sleep(10)
    print ("done")
  except Exception as err:
    print("Exception for subreddit {}, {}".format(subreddit, err))
  t= random.randint(505,825)
  seconds = "Sleeping for {} seconds before proceeding".format(t)
  print(seconds)
  time.sleep(t)
```

Comment: when do you expect your program to stop?  Is it crashing because of errors? Throwing Exceptions?  Being manually turned off?

Comment: You can use a excel or csv to record the status. Try openpyxl.

Comment: @KevinCrum its just because of replit , the platform I'm using to host my python bot, i guess replit restarts to save resources not really sure.

Comment: @bereal I'm new to this website and I don't really know how to delete .